# How to run Jenkins pipeline for multi module projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multi-module

In my project, I have multiple modules(consist of multiple directories and each directory having it's own dockerfile and pom.xml files). I have created a Jenkins pipeline for it. But every time I run the jenkins pipeline each module gets build and deployed, which wastes lot of time. Is there any way, to deploy only a particular module that time through my jenkins pipeline. So that it saves my time.

As of now I am commenting manually the module which I don't want to run in my jenkins pipeline, is there any way, I don't have to comment the module, but can run only the module, I requires through jenkins pipeline. I don't want to create separate jenkins pipeline for each modules, because there are lots of modules.

I don't want to use multi-branch pipeline since, all the module codes are present in one single branch only, and placing modules in different branches will change my code structure.

Is there any plugin or mechanism through which I can do build for only particular module that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `when` and `change set` on this page https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

You could then run certain module build stages depending on if changes to that modules code have been committed.

Comment: It should be like, I can trigger that module anytime, not only just when code is committed

Comment: Use a build parameter then to select which module(s) to build then use when expression clause(s) to check for the parameter and build as needed